# Justification for the Axiom of Union

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Is the Axiom of Union included in $\sf ZFC $ because one cannot construct the union of two sets using the Axiom Schema of Specification?

Comment: A set is a plastic bag containing (what else?) other plastic bags. Without Union, there seems to be no way to even take the contents of two bags and pouring them into a new bag.

Comment: There can be some variation in how axioms are set up, but typically the union axiom allows you to take the union of all the elements of a set of sets, not just of two sets.

Comment: @dfeuer the fact you've just mentioned is quite obvious, but important nonetheless.

Comment: In class-set theories, the notion of a binary union (of classes) is no longer strictly less general than the notion of the union of a set; this also is obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specification has the form
$$
\{x\in X \mid \psi(x)\}
$$
Where $\psi$ is some property.

Note that you need a base set $X$ where the selected elements come from.

This is not a problem for the intersection of two sets $A$ and $B$, which you can write down as
$$
A \cap B = \{x\in A \mid x\in B\}.
$$

However for the union $A\cup B$, a priori there is no suitable base set where you can select all the elements.

Comment: EXACTLY the reason I'm asking this question. Thanks for the verification, mate :)